# BD8043S Step down convertor

Tags: dc-dc-converter

i have 12 - 5v car USB charger and inside have chip BD8043S 8 pin chip two capacitors, one diode and ferid. i looking for datasheet but for this chip i cant found. there no resistors like MC34063, it is possible to change Vout to 3.7v on it.

Thank you...

Comment: Why do you want to reuse this chip in particular, instead of getting your own DC-DC IC?

Comment: i have more then 10 cigarette plugs 12v to USB charger but all of this use BD8043S. i need datasheet of this IC for i drop down voltage to 3.7v. I need just for test. I know this is Chinese IC but if somebody before joke with this IC can write here.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense -- do you not have anyone where you are that you can buy a DC/DC IC from?

Comment: i want finding datasheet from this IC, maybe i'm first who looking for this IC but if company use like DC-DC i want to know specs of it. I mean this is cheap IC but works fine for 24/5v 12/5v in your vehicle. Also you can finding this just for $1 in dollartree.

Comment: Vout = 3.7 V, are you trying to charge a li-ion battery with it?

Comment: no... i have bluetooth speaker stereo i modify for AUX plug but i don't wanna use battery because can not turn off when i turn off engine / amplifier. I trying to do step down voltage like battery power to 3.7v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't adjust Vout, AD85063 is a fixed voltage step-down switching converter. The resistors are already inside of the IC, you can see them just before the comparator.

[image]

It's possible to get 3.7v by adding some extra circuitry but in my opinion there won't be enough space inside the charger.

Answer (score -2):

OK guys, i spend lot of time and finally i found datasheet for  **BD8043S**. it's equivalent with **AD85063**.